# UnboundLocalError at /org_list/ local variable 'orgs' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, python-3.x

I encounter a problem when i wanted to do pagination.
here is my view.py:

```
class OrgView(View):   
    def get(self,request):
        all_orgs=CourseOrg.objects.all()
        org_nums=all_orgs.count()
        all_citys=CityDict.objects.all()

        try:
            page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            page = 1
            p = Paginator(all_orgs, 5, request=request)                
            orgs = p.page(page)


        return  render(request,'org-list.html',{
            "all_orgs":orgs,
            "all_citys":all_citys,
            "org_nums":org_nums,
        })
```

here is org-list.html:

```
{% for course_org in all_orgs.object_list %}
                <dl class="des difdes">
                    <dt>
                        <a href="org-detail-homepage.html">
                            <img width="200" height="120" class="scrollLoading" data-url="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ course_org.image }}"/>
                        </a>
                    </dt>
                    <dd>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                             <a href="org-detail-homepage.html">
                                 <h1>{{ course_org.name }}</h1>
                                 <div class="pic fl">

                                         <img src="{% static 'images/authentication.png' %}"/>

                                         <img src="{% static 'images/gold.png' %}"/>

                                 </div>
                             </a>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="cont">
                            <li class="first"><p class="pic9">course number：<span>{{ course_org.click_nums}}</span></p><p class="c7">student number：<span>{{ course_org.fav_nums }}</span></p></li>
                            <li class="c8" style="padding-left:18px;">{{ course_org.address }}</li>
                                                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                                   </dl>
            {% endfor %}
```

when i run the org-list.html, the error is :UnboundLocalError at /org_list/
local variable 'orgs' referenced before assignment

my python is 3.6.4 and django is 2.0.1

thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a better look at the error message and your code: the only place where you're defining the `orgs` variable is on line 12:

```
orgs = p.page(page)
```

which is inside an `except` block, meaning that that piece of code won't get evaluated unless the `PageNotAnInteger` exception is thrown.

You should set the `orgs` variable to a default value prior to the `try/except` block, or within the `try` as well.